# Remove specific character based on Hex value from string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

Now, I want to remove all extra `\x` characters before hex value, and keep the hex value as string. For example,

Convert the string

`"\\x1D\\x06\\x1BH\\x18+Congratulations!\\x1D\\x00"`

to the content of new string

`1d 06 1b 48 18 2b 43 6f 6e 67 72 61 74 75 6c 61 74 69 6f 6e 73 21 1d 00`

How to do it in JavaScript efficiently?

Comment: A start:  `x = "\x1D\x06\x1BH\x18+Congratulations!\x1D\x00" ; x.split('').map(function(c){ return Number(c.charCodeAt(0)).toString(16) })` yields `["1d", "6", "1b", "48", "18", "2b", "43", "6f", "6e", "67", "72", "61", "74", "75", "6c", "61", "74", "69", "6f", "6e", "73", "21", "1d", "0"]` but it doesn't pad the 6 or the 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems works well with the following codes

```
var ss = "\\x1D\\x06\\x1BH\\x18+Congratulations!\\x1D\\x00";

ss.replace(/\\x[0-9a-fA-F]{2}/g, function(v){ 
   return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(v.substr(2), 16));
});
```

Comment: You changed the string !